# git submodules: Which repository shall be used as the 'submodule'?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a private git repository (repos 'private') with a bunch of files in them
I frequently edit. Some of these files are published on a website. It is tedious
to update these files every time I make a small change. I therefore thought of
using git submodules in the following way: I set up a second (now public) git
repository ('public'), and put in all files which appear on the website. The
website then provides links to these files in 'public'. Once I edit one of the
files in 'private' which are also in 'public', the changes in 'public' will be
visible (after a simple git command) and the file changes will thus be visible
on the website. My questions are:

1) Is this a good approach to deal with the problem?

2) I read about `git submodule update --remote --merge` but I'm still not 100%
sure whether this updates the submodule to changes in the main project or
exactly the opposite. I frequently see the wor 'upstream' used in explanations
but couldn't find an exact definition.

3) If submodules are mainly used in the sense that one updates the main project
to changes in the submodules, would I then have to create the 'private'
repository as a submodule and the 'public' one as the main project? (because I
would like to track changes to 'private' from within 'public')

[I thought I still keep these questions in a single post as they are quite related.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using submodules adds quite a bit of complexity.

It seems like it would be easier to have a single repository, with a directory 'private' and a directory 'public'. The directory 'public' could contain symlinks to the files in 'private'.

This would allow you to have 2 types of files but avoid the complexity of submodules.

Another option would be to have your build system handle this: have only a single directory containing all files, and have a Makefile target which copies the public files to another directory.

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping. Indeed `submodules` create another level of complexity. But with the git server I use it is not possible to have both public and private subfolders in the same project. Also, symlinks are then not working as (if you have two different projects) simply the locally correct but remotely meaningless relative path is committed and the file not found. I ended up using hard links in the second (public) repository. That worked for some test files, haven't tried it 'big scale' yet. [I  accept your answer as it led me in the right direction]